# c# dictionary not working?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Not sure exactly whats going on here as it does not give me an error message when I am trying to run this part of the code.

Basically its supposed to put the text from the dictionary into a richtextbox when the option is selected from the drop down menue

Like if I select "Outage" from the drop down it should put the contents of that into the richtextbox

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> templates = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        // Templates
        templates.Add("Outage", "Server Name: \nTest: \nTest (test): \n");
        templates.Add("Out", "test: \nTest: \nTest:");
        templates.Add("Custom", @"C:\Users\johnathan_jackson\Downloads\Remedy Tool\Templates\custom templates\test.txt");
        templates.Add("Test", "Server Name: \nTest: \nTest: \n");
        templates.Add("Basic", "OS: \nIP Address: \nApplications affected: \nWhen did this last work: \n Number of users affected: \nSpecific error message: \nTroubleshooting steps taken \nDetailed Resolution \nIf not service resolvable, Why:");
        templates.Add("Xerox", "Serial Number (mandatory): \nAsset Number: \nContact Phone Number: \nContact e-mail address: \nFull Address: \nDescription of the Supplies that are needed: \nPart # (if customer has it): \nError message (if any): \nLocation (Building/Floor/etc): \nModel #: \n");

        NavigateURL navigateBrowser = new NavigateURL();

        InitializeComponent();

        Remedy_Automate.AllowNavigation = true;
        Remedy_Automate.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        Remedy_Automate.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(navigateBrowser.DocumentState);

        // GetInfo from Remedy to these controls
        navigateBrowser.cIncidentID = incidentID_Entry;
        navigateBrowser.cEmployeeID = employeeID_Entry;
        navigateBrowser.cEmployeeName = employeeName_Entry;
        navigateBrowser.cPhoneNumber = phoneNumber_Entry;

        navigateBrowser.cNotes = Notes_Entry;

        getinfo.Click += new System.EventHandler(navigateBrowser.GetInfoClick);
        sendinfo.Click += new System.EventHandler(navigateBrowser.ModifyInfo);

        browserTabControl.Selecting += browserTabControl_Selecting;
        browserTabControl.HandleCreated += browserTabControl_HandleCreated;

        wTemplates.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

        // set browser control in 'cNavigateURL' class
        navigateBrowser.BrowserInstance = Remedy_Automate;
        navigateBrowser.NavigateToUrl("http://fit.honeywell.com/arsys");

    }// Form1

    private void sendinfo_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string notestext = Notes_Entry.Text;
        Console.WriteLine(notestext);
    }

    private void template_selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String pTempText = wTemplates.Text;
        Console.WriteLine(pTempText);
        switch(pTempText)
        {
            case "Outage":
                Notes_Entry.Text = templates[pTempText];
                break;
            case "Basic":
            Notes_Entry.Text = templates[pTempText];
                break;
            case "Custom":
                Notes_Entry.Text = templates[pTempText];
                break;
            case "Out":
                Notes_Entry.Text = templates[pTempText];
                break;
        }
```

Comment: InitializeComponent(); has to be on the first place in Form1 constructor

Comment: What error are you getting?  Have you run it in the debugger to see what the variable values are when you get the exception?

Comment: Among other things, you don't need that switch block.  Just check if the dictionary contains the key, and if so, set it.  Notice how all your case blocks have the same code?

Comment: Unless you do it elsewhere, you never link the combo box's SelectedIndexChanged to your handler, thus it's never called

Comment: @Timon Post - not really, no.

Comment: I moved the InitializeComponent(); up and it's still not working

Im not getting an error and Im still new to programming so im not sure where to check the variable values at

Since Im new to programming not sure on how to do it that way,sorry. links to an example would help though

Comment: What is the message that you are getting?  The exception might have some information that would indicate the cause, but we can't reproduce the problem just from a sample of your code.  Learn (either on your own by reading documentation or by someone helping you) how to use the debugger to see variable values, and/or post more _relevant_ information to indicate what the problem is.

Comment: @D Stanley Isn't that what this place is for? To ask for help one certain issues you are having? At least thats what I thought anyways. If you could maybe link me to a good article or something I could read I will definitely try to get the information that you guys are needing.

Comment: @Imcoolyourenot Search your code for `wTemplates.SelectedIndexChanged += template_selected`. If you can't find it anywhere, then there's your problem

Comment: Listen to CDSpace, put a breakpoint at your switch statement and see if it ever even gets hit.  We think it won't.

Comment: So I didnt find that line of code in there so I added it  inside the 'private void template_selected(object sender, EventArgs e)' But it's still not working. I also tried to add a breakpoint which didnt seem to work either. also I added a console.writeline("debug") but debug does not come up in the outline.. Im sorry if this is the wrong site to ask these kinds of questions since I am so new. I've been learning by myself and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where your binding your Dictionary to your combo box. You need to add the following:

```
wTemplates.DisplayMember = "Key";
wTemplates.ValueMember = "Value";
wTemplates.DataSource = new BindingSource(templates, null);
```

I would also recommend that you add another entry at the top of your dictionary so that Item 0 is not a real choice, such as ("Select Item", ""). This is because the selected_item event will fire when your combo box gets filled the first time.

So your code would look like this in the Form1():

```
        // Templates
        templates.Add("Select Item", "");
        templates.Add("Outage", @"Server Name: \nTest: \nTest (test): \n");
        templates.Add("Out", @"test: \nTest: \nTest:");
        templates.Add("Custom", @"C:\Users\johnathan_jackson\Downloads\Remedy Tool\Templates\custom templates\test.txt");
        templates.Add("Test", @"Server Name: \nTest: \nTest: \n");
        templates.Add("Basic", @"OS: \nIP Address: \nApplications affected: \nWhen did this last work: \n Number of users affected: \nSpecific error message: \nTroubleshooting steps taken \nDetailed Resolution \nIf not service resolvable, Why:");
        templates.Add("Xerox", @"Serial Number (mandatory): \nAsset Number: \nContact Phone Number: \nContact e-mail address: \nFull Address: \nDescription of the Supplies that are needed: \nPart # (if customer has it): \nError message (if any): \nLocation (Building/Floor/etc): \nModel #: \n");

        wTemplates.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

        wTemplates.SelectedIndexChanged += template_selected;

        wTemplates.DisplayMember = "Key";
        wTemplates.ValueMember = "Value";
        wTemplates.DataSource = new BindingSource(templates, null);
```

Then have the handler actually have the code in it.

```
    private void template_selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String pTempText = wTemplates.Text;
        Console.WriteLine(pTempText);
        switch (pTempText)
        {
            case "Outage":
                Notes_Entry.Text = templates[pTempText];
                break;
            case "Basic":
                Notes_Entry.Text = templates[pTempText];
                break;
            case "Custom":
                Notes_Entry.Text = templates[pTempText];
                break;
            case "Out":
                Notes_Entry.Text = templates[pTempText];
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It's working. Such a simple fix once you look at it haha. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, please mark it as the answer if it solved your issue. Thanks!